# cloudwatch alarm for Autoscaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

how to setup cloudwatch alarm for Autoscaling group when its scaling down Mincapacity Instances using cloudformation template.

I mean need alarm when all the Instances were "OutofService" basically this will happen when Instance failed ELB healthcheck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add an alarm based on the CloudTrail metric `HealtlyHostCount`? If you set a low threshold, you will get warned when there are no healthy instances.
You can see the metrics documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-cloudwatch-metrics.html)